# Exploding keys and values in a dictionary subset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to create a way of exchanging the keys and values in a Pandas DataFrame of the [USGS/WWF HydroBASINS dataset](https://www.hydrosheds.org/pages/hydrobasins) but only for a specific subset. My entire dataframe is roughly 500 000 rows long so I only want to perform this for key, value pairs that are relevant to an intial value.

Assuming that a DataFrame/Dictionary is structured as 'upstream' and 'downstream':

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6], 3: [7, 8]}
```

Therefore, 2 is downstream of [1], 4 is downstream of [1 and 2], 7 is downstream of [1, 3].

The challenging part is that I don't want to determine the relationships for all keys,values as this would take a very long time. For a large dataset of hydrological tributaries, depending on where one starts, this could lead to creating a dataframe that explodes with keys if the upstream values are collected and determined for all keys.

At the end of the day, when providing one key, I would like to have returned all the upstream keys. Expanding all values would resemble this:

```
{1: [], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [1, 2], 5: [1, 2], 6: [1, 2], 7: [1, 3], 8: [1, 3], ...}
```

Whereas I would rather simply return:

```
5: [1, 2]
```

I haven't had much luck working with `DefaultDicts` as some posts have suggested but this is probably because I'm not familiar enough with them.

UPDATE:

In order to better understand, the relevant fields of the data frame are 'HYBAS_ID': The ID number of the basin, 'NEXT_DOWN': The basin that it flows into, (and 'MAIN_BAS': The greater watershed ID (e.g. Mississippi, Saint Lawrence, James Bay, Rio Grande, etc.))

here's what the unoptimized code looks like:

```
def get_upstream_hydrobasins(basin_dataframe, basin_id):
    upstream_mask = basin_dataframe['NEXT_DOWN'] == basin_id
    iter_upstream = basin_dataframe[upstream_mask]['HYBAS_ID']
    return iter_upstream

basin_ID = <ID of some hydroBASIN>
df = pd.read_csv(table)
row_id = df['HYBAS_ID'] == basin_ID

# Some code to subset the number of potential sub-basins using regions
main_basin_id = df[row_id]['MAIN_BAS']
main_basin_mask = df['MAIN_BAS'] == main_basin_id.values[0]
main_basin_df = df[main_basin_mask]

all_basins = list(main_basin_df[row_id]['HYBAS_ID'].values)
for b in all_basins:
    tmp = get_upstream_hydrobasins(main_basin_df, b)
    if len(tmp):
        all_basins.extend(tmp.values)
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to optimize this code.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe what you are trying to compute. If you have a basin N, you are trying to compute ... all of the upstream basins? Say if you found contaminated water in a given basin, would you want to compute a list of potential sources? It is easy to get lost in the abstract numbers and data structures.

Comment: I think a tree data structure might be best here, though off the top of my head I can't give an example implementation for this case. That way you are only traversing from the leaves up and not any extraneous paths. The issue is the data structure you have now *forces* you to iterate through the entire dict to check membership in each value

Comment: @Leonid Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to figure out. Once I have the IDs of the upstream basins, I query for the geometries that are eventually dissolved/merged to return a shapefile of the upstream region.

Comment: @C.Nivs You're right. Most of those that I've spoken to have suggested taht iterating is the only way forward. I'm wondering at this point if maybe there is some optimization possible by leveraging Pandas.

Comment: I am then confused about what exactly this would look like when drawn out. `{1: [2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [4, 5, 6], 3: [5, 6, 7, 8]}`. For example, why does 4 have two things upstream: 1 and 2?

Comment: @Leonid I think it's just extra information. This should only require *direct* downstream, which will make the iteration more straightforward and membership tests a bit less tricky: `{1: [2,3], 2: [4,5,6], 3: [5,6,7,8]}`. Not sure if the data needs additional transformation for that to occur

Comment: @Leonid That's an error on my part. It is direct downstream, ie: basins are tributaries to only one basin but are contributed to by multiple (1:N).